# Unable to insert record from user-defined into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

**Scenario**

I've created a store procedure in which I'm taking a User-Defined table as a parameter then First I'll check if `Role_ID` and `Form_ID` is exists then I'll update my existing table. Otherwise I'll insert into existing table.

**Problem**

After writing insert query in my store procedure I got below error while altering my store procedure.

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_SAVE_AND_UPDATE, Line 17
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp".
>   Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_SAVE_AND_UPDATE, Line 17
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Temp".

**Below is my SP code:**

```
CREATE TYPE _ROLERIGHTSSCHEMA as Table (
    _Role_ID int,
    _Form_ID int,
    _Form_Name varchar(100),
    _Can_View bit,
    _Can_Edit bit,
    _Can_Prepare_By bit,
    _Can_Change_Status_By bit,
    _Prepared_By_ID int,
    _Prepared_Date datetime
)

ALTER PROCEDURE SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_SAVE_AND_UPDATE
(@Temp _ROLERIGHTSSCHEMA ReadOnly)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ROLE_RIGHTS WHERE Role_ID = @Temp.Role_ID AND Form_ID = @Temp.Form_ID)
    BEGIN
        Update Role_Rights
        set Can_View = t._Can_View,
            Can_Edit = t._Can_Edit,
            Can_Prepare_By = t._Can_Prepare_By,
            Can_Change_Status_By = _Can_Change_Status_By,
            Modified_By_ID = 0,
            Modified_Date = GETDATE()
            From @Temp t
            WHERE Role_Rights.Role_ID = t._Role_ID and Role_Rights.Form_ID = t._Form_ID
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Role_Rights (
            Role_ID,
            Form_ID,
            Can_View,
            Can_Edit,
            Can_Prepare_By,
            Can_Change_Status_By,
            Prepared_By_ID,
            Prepared_Date
        ) SELECT _Role_ID, _Form_ID, _Can_View, _Can_Edit, _Can_Prepare_By, _Can_Change_Status_By, 0, GETDATE() FROM @Temp
    END
END
```

[image]

Comment: You should consider not using the SP_ prefix. It can cause performance issues and some other interesting challenges. Either choose a different prefix or even better, no prefix at all. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update/insert multiple records at once use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_SAVE_AND_UPDATE
(@Temp _ROLERIGHTSSCHEMA ReadOnly)
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE Role_Rights rr
    USING @Temp t
      ON rr.Role_ID = t._Role_ID 
         and rr.Form_ID = t._Form_ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       Update set Can_View = t._Can_View,
                    Can_Edit = t._Can_Edit,
                    Can_Prepare_By = t._Can_Prepare_By,
                    Can_Change_Status_By = _Can_Change_Status_By,
                    Modified_By_ID = 0,
                    Modified_Date = GETDATE()
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT ( Role_ID,
            Form_ID,
            Can_View,
            Can_Edit,
            Can_Prepare_By,
            Can_Change_Status_By,
            Prepared_By_ID,
            Prepared_Date)
       VALUES (_Role_ID, _Form_ID, _Can_View, _Can_Edit,
               _Can_Prepare_By, _Can_Change_Status_By, 0, GETDATE() );
END;
```

**EDIT:**

`MERGE` over `IF EXISTS/UPDATE/INSERT set based`:

```
Single insert   -- no difference
Single update   -- no difference
Multiple insert -- no difference
Multiple update -- no difference
Multiple insert/update:  MERGE     -- will handle it correctly 
                         IF EXISTS -- you will lose records to insert
```

---

UPDATE/INSERT without IF part:

```
Update Role_Rights
        set Can_View = t._Can_View,
            Can_Edit = t._Can_Edit,
            Can_Prepare_By = t._Can_Prepare_By,
            Can_Change_Status_By = _Can_Change_Status_By,
            Modified_By_ID = 0,
            Modified_Date = GETDATE()
            From @Temp t
WHERE Role_Rights.Role_ID = t._Role_ID and Role_Rights.Form_ID = t._Form_ID;

INSERT INTO Role_Rights (
        Role_ID,
        Form_ID,
        Can_View,
        Can_Edit,
        Can_Prepare_By,
        Can_Change_Status_By,
        Prepared_By_ID,
        Prepared_Date
    ) 
 SELECT _Role_ID, _Form_ID, _Can_View, _Can_Edit,
        _Can_Prepare_By, _Can_Change_Status_By, 0, GETDATE() 
 FROM @Temp t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM Role_Rights rr
                   WHERE rr.Role_ID = t._Role_ID 
                     and rr.Form_ID = t._Form_ID);
```

Comment: Before I wrote if condition above update query working fine. I've update a single record but after writing `IF` condition my insert code not working.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan Using IF/UPDATE/INSERT won't work for multiple records.

Comment: First I checked your answer and its worked fine. But after @smor answer I just edit my `IF` condition and its worked Like a charm.

Comment: what is the main difference between your answer and @smor answer as I found both answer useful but I'm confused which one I choosed for my code.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your exists clause is not correctly formed - and that is throwing the error. You have:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ROLE_RIGHTS WHERE Role_ID = @Temp.Role_ID AND Form_ID = @Temp.Form_ID)
```

But it should be:

```
if exists (select * from ROLE_RIGHTS as rr inner join @Temp as tp on rr.Role_ID = tp._Role_ID and rr.Form_ID = tp._Form_ID)
```

That correction is pointless - as @lad2025 has already mentioned.

Comment: There is big drawback when this approach is used (when @Temp table have both records to update/insert -- there will be no insert part at all). Of course OP could use CURSOR and handle each row separately but it will be much slower than set based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try with multiple IF clauses within statement after ELSE, check if this works

```
CREATE TYPE _ROLERIGHTSSCHEMA as Table (
        _Role_ID int,
        _Form_ID int,
        _Form_Name varchar(100),
        _Can_View bit,
        _Can_Edit bit,
        _Can_Prepare_By bit,
        _Can_Change_Status_By bit,
        _Prepared_By_ID int,
        _Prepared_Date datetime
    )


    ALTER PROCEDURE SP_SETUP_ROLES_RIGHTS_SAVE_AND_UPDATE
    (@Temp _ROLERIGHTSSCHEMA ReadOnly)
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ROLE_RIGHTS WHERE Role_ID = @Temp.Role_ID AND Form_ID = @Temp.Form_ID)
        BEGIN
            Update Role_Rights
            set Can_View = t._Can_View,
                Can_Edit = t._Can_Edit,
                Can_Prepare_By = t._Can_Prepare_By,
                Can_Change_Status_By = _Can_Change_Status_By,
                Modified_By_ID = 0,
                Modified_Date = GETDATE()
                From @Temp t
                WHERE Role_Rights.Role_ID = t._Role_ID and Role_Rights.Form_ID = t._Form_ID
            END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ROLE_RIGHTS WHERE Role_ID = @Temp.Role_ID AND Form_ID = @Temp.Form_ID)
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO Role_Rights (
                Role_ID,
                Form_ID,
                Can_View,
                Can_Edit,
                Can_Prepare_By,
                Can_Change_Status_By,
                Prepared_By_ID,
                Prepared_Date
            ) SELECT _Role_ID, _Form_ID, _Can_View, _Can_Edit, _Can_Prepare_By, _Can_Change_Status_By, 0, GETDATE() FROM @Temp
        END
        END 
    END
```